# Extract all the section numbers of a word document using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have a word document that contains multiple sections and here is the sample

```
Document History
        Table of contents
        1. Introduction
        ...
        2. Purpose
        ...
        3. Scope
        ...
        4. Detailed levels of document
        ...
        4.1 Next level
            ...
        4.2 sub levels
            ...
            4.2.1 
            ...
            4.2.2
            ...
                4.2.2.1
                ...
```

I want to extract the section numbers of all levels and the output should be like:
`1 2 3 4 4.1 4.2 4.2.1 4.2.2 4.2.2.1`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import docx

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Word Documents", "*.docx")])

doc = docx.Document(file_path)

#Something wrong here: this extracts only the headings, but i do not want the headings, rather i just need #the section numbers alone of all levels
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':
        print(paragraph.text)
```

Comment: So what does this print?

Comment: It prints only the title: 
`code`Introduction
Purpose
Scope
Detailed levels of document`code`

and it is not printing the numbers as well as sub sections or headings and their numbers